# Observable and interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, casting

I have defined the following interface for models:

```
export interface IModel {
    fillFromResponse(body: any);
}
```

So, in a model (for example, Token) i impement the interface:

```
import { IModel } from './imodel';

export class Token implements IModel { 

    public value: string;

    public fillFromResponse(body: any) {
        let token = new Token();
        token.value = body.access_token;
        return token;
    }
}
```

With that i hope have one callback for all observable map or catch functions:

```
public handleResponse(instance: IModel, observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<IModel> {
    return observable.map(
        (response: Response) => {
            return instance.fillFromResponse(response.json());
        }
    ).catch((error: any) => 
        Observable.throw(error.json().messages[0] || 'Unknown error')
    );
}
```

So, in a service i have the following method:

```
public login(credentials): Observable<Token> {
    let url = this.api.getUrl('/users/tokens');
    let options = this.api.getOptions();

    return this.api.handleResponse(
        new Token(),
        this.http.post(url, credentials, options)
    );
}
```

But i get:

> Type Observable< IModel > is not assignable to Observable< Token >

Why interfaces doesn't work like another languages like PHP ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your code.

1. Your handleResponse method's return type is `Observable<IModel>`. And you're trying to return that from a method suppsed to return an `Observable<Token>`. So that can't be correct: all IModel instances are not instances of Token.
2. Your handleResponse method actually returns an `Observable<void>`, since in the map() callback, you're returning the result of fillFromResponse(), and fillFromResponse()'s return type is void.

So, the code should rather look like this (untested):

```
export interface IModel<T> {
  fillFromResponse(body: any): T;
}

export class Token implements IModel<Token> { 

  public value: string;

  public fillFromResponse(body: any): Token {
    let token = new Token();
    token.value = body.access_token;
    return token;
  }
}
```

Or rather, since I guess you actually want to fill the original token instead of creating a new one:

```
export class Token implements IModel<Token> { 

  public value: string;

  public fillFromResponse(body: any): Token {
    this.value = body.access_token;
    return this;
  }
}
```

And finally

```
public handleResponse<T>(instance: IModel<T>, observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<T> {
  return observable.map(
    (response: Response) => instance.fillFromResponse(response.json());
  ).catch((error: any) => 
    Observable.throw(error.json().messages[0] || 'Unknown error')
  );
}
```

That said, I think all ths is a bad idea and makes things much more complex than they should be. If you really want a generic handleResponse method, you can just pass it the callback function to pass to the map() operator. But doing that is useless, since you could simply call map() on the observable returned by handleResponse() int he first place:

```
public login(credentials): Observable<Token> {
  let url = this.api.getUrl('/users/tokens');
  let options = this.api.getOptions();

  return this.api.handleResponse(
    this.http.post(url, credentials, options)
  ).map(body => new Token(body.access_token));
}
```

Also note that, if you used the new HttpClient instead of the soon deprecated Http service, you wouldn't even have to map the response to json.